Top Menu bar missing some parts ( shading, proportional editing and so on )
I just moved to Blender 4.0 and can't find shading, proportional editing and so on. What could be wrong? It resets when loading factory settings, but I made settings comfortable for me and don't want to tweak them again.


The 'shading' tab is on your screenshot... Did you import your old settings from Blender >3.X when opening the 4.0 for the first time ? Blender always proposes to import previous settings like keybindings, theme, extras... when installing a new version.

Blender loads the UI setup/layout when you open a blend file. If you open an older blend file the settings may be invalid. In this case, go to the User Preferences (menu Edit > User Preferences...), choose the "Save & Load" entry on the left, and untick the [_] Load UI checkbox in the first section (Blend Files). Then the UI doesn't change when you open blend files and the Blender 4 UI layout will be retained when you open older Blend files.

Retopoflow addon was causing problems. As I removed it, everything came back normal. Thanks guys for assistance!
